# "User is not allowed to do action" following a DeprecationWarning

Tags: node.js, mongodb

While working on some new (very simple) server code, I connected and inserted MongoDB URL code in order to "deploy" it on MongoDB Atlas.

However, I get the following warning:

> (node:3396) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is
>   deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
>   parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

This doesn't prevent my code from deploying to the server, and still allows me to send requests with a local testing tool (Postman). However, after my requests are sent, I get the following message in VS Code:

```
{ MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [insert] on [agenda.contacts]
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mymachine\agenda\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:443:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at processMessage (C:\Users\mymachine\agenda\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:364:10)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mymachine\agenda\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:533:15)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  ok: 0,
```

I suspect this is probably a version error, however this is out of my area of expertise.

My setup is very simple and has only the Atlas cluster connected on MongoDB website.

MongoDB still provides all the analytics I need, so it doesn't seem to have a problem there.

I've already tried changing `mongoClient.connect` code from `useMongoClient: true` to `useNewUrlParser: true`, but it only changes the warning message code from `(node:3396)` to `(node:1092)`.

```
mongoose.connect(
    '*inserted mongodb url code, copied from CONNECTION STRING ONLY");
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true
    }
```

Since I have never used MongoDB, I believe my issue is on that software.

I copied the CONNECTION STRING ONLY instead of FULL DRIVER EXAMPLE (both provide a code to insert into my code in VS Code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are a couple of different issues here, but one thing to note is that the number in `(node:1234)` is simply an indicator of which line of your code is causing the error or warning. If the number changes, you should go to the new line number and look for issues there, as well.

Comment: *facepalm*

Thanks for the heads up. I just had no clue what ANY of my issues were. This is definitely a heads up to small details!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As to the (node(1234)) issue solved above, it was in regards to a Warning about a newer version, as to call `useNewUrlParser: true`instead of `useMongoClient: true`.

As to the "MongoError", I was, instead of hardcoding my password, calling a `+ process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW +`and sending my password to file `./nodemon.json`.

After changing both errors, code ran smoothly. I, however, will have to find a new way to send password, instead of hardcoding it.

Thank you all who has helped.